# How Do I Enable Error Throwing In PlatformIO? (I'm getting g++ errors.)

Tags: c++, arduino, g++, platformio

I am trying to throw errors in my Arduino Ethernet code (`if (error) throw error`) and handle (really ignore: `catch(Error error) {}`) them. Sadly, I get errors like:

```
src\main.cpp: In function 'void loop()':
src\main.cpp:29:35: error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
     } catch (Error error) {
                    ^
```

I read that I need to add the following to my `platformio.ini` file to enable error handling:

```
build_flags = -fexceptions
build_unflags = -fno-exceptions
```

Now on the compilation, I get this:

```
<artificial>:(.text+0xaf8): undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
<artificial>:(.text+0xb0a): undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
...
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x5c): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x5e): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x116): undefined reference to `setup'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x1fa): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x1fe): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please add your compiler command line/makefile to the question. Have you linked the C++ runtimes library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the AVR architecture (avr-g++). As you can see in [its FAQ](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_cplusplus), it's not supported:

> Exceptions are not supported. Since exceptions are enabled by default in the C++ frontend, they explicitly need to be turned off using -fno-exceptions in the compiler options. Failing this, the linker will complain about an undefined external reference to __gxx_personality_sj0.

It's there just because of common c++ frontend and because exceptions are enabled by default.

However for example in the STM32duino (STM32 Arm MCUs) it's possible to use -fexceptions (as well as STL and many more)

Comment: what for. Exceptions are probably 76k FLASH more

Comment: Interesting. You learn something new every day! Thanks